# how to move and merge folders in OSX Mavericks?

Tags: macos, filesystem

I have 2 subfolders (which in itself contains many subfolders) in my main folder.

e.g.

```
main folder
== subfolder1
==== folder1
==== folder2
== subfolder2
==== folder1
==== folder3
==== folder4
```

some things in subfolder2 are already in subfolder1. If I drag and drop subfolder2 into subfolder1, it will ask me to replace existing subfolders thus losing things. The only way to merge the folders that I know of is to press the option key. But this only makes a copy. This still requires me to delete the unneeded folder.

I want to move subfolder2 into subfolder1 and merge their contents. How can I do it? Thanks much :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## 1 Quick answer

#### Enter this command in Terminal:

`cp -r -n ./srcFolder/ ./targetFolder/` 
Remove the `-n` if you want to overwrite duplicates.

**Update:**
`ditto source target` will also do the trick.

Files in source folder overwrite any duplicates in target folder.

Add -v for details (`ditto -v source target`)

*via [How to Merge Folders on Mac OS X Without Losing All Your Files (Seriously)](http://www.howtogeek.com/198043/how-to-merge-folders-on-mac-os-x-without-losing-all-your-files-seriously/)*

## 2 Use Finder (surprisingly more complex)

Possibly a duplicate of [Where did folder "merge" or "keep both" go in OS X 10.9 Mavericks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/where-did-folder-merge-or-keep-both-go-in-os-x-10-9-mavericks), but I'll sum up:

The weird thing is, the folders can't have any duplicate files if you want to merge.

If you're merging two folders that don't have any duplicate files between them, you will see the merge option if you hold the option key.
[image]

However, if the folders you're merging contain any files with the same name, the merge option won't show up.
[image: If folders contain any duplicate items]

In that case, you basically have two options:

1. use the command line or
2. manually remove duplicates, then click & drag + hold option to merge.

Comment: Just for kicks I made a script that does this, and then deletes the folder using a trash function I have. `merge() {
    echo "Merging $(basename $1) into $(basename $2)";
    ditto $@;
    trash $1;
  }`

Comment: At least in Mojave it no longer works as you describe. I can merge folders containing files with the same names. https://i.imgur.com/cXc0SiJ.png