# How do I merge folders using finder?

Tags: finder, filesystem, utilities

I have a folder (let's name it main-folder and it's mounted via smb) that contains lots of files and subfolders. I want to copy half of the contents of main-folder to a local subfolder (let's call it my-folder). My problem is that one folder is common between main-folder and my-folder. And even though I have pressed the option key, I do not get the merge option.

I know I can use rsync and other similar commands which I've done lots of time. EXCEPT I can't use it this time as I am only copying half of the files/folders. Too tedious to write an exception list.

**I was hoping for a similar behaviour when dragging files/folders in Windows Explorer.**

Any ideas on how to make it work? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just hold the Option button when you drag the folder, then will be available the "Keep Both"/"Combine" option so you can merge the folders. Just like the Windows default behavior.

[Where did folder "merge" or "keep both" go in OS X 10.9 Mavericks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107152/where-did-folder-merge-or-keep-both-go-in-os-x-10-9-mavericks)